# How to confirm the file attributes of a document

Tags: windows, file-attributes

Is there a way of confirming that the file attributes of a document are correct/genuine.

For example, the date created, modified etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be a difference between correct and genuine. These properties are whatever they are and usually automatically updated. Some apps may modify these values for their own purposes, however. This is not a common practice though.

The easiest way to confirm these values is to remember them. This shouldn't be too hard for a single file. If they change when they shouldn't, then something is doing that.

If you need more robust checking then you'll want to start by creating a [list of the files and the attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25977208/creating-a-list-with-file-name-date-created-date-modified) at some point and later [comparing](http://winmerge.org/) that list to a freshly made one.